# Output the file in way we wanted

Tags: bash, shell

I have ssh config file which contains so many servers from google,aws and some remote servers.I wanted to have a bash function that will output only the Host and the HostName of the server so I dont have to remember there public DNS to check my webapps.

Sample Server Config in my ssh config looks like this

```
Host aws_server
        User                    rand
        HostName                65.2.25.152
        Port                    8000
        IdentityFile            PEM PATH
        ServerAliveInterval     120
        ServerAliveCountMax     30
```

I want the output like

```
aws_server                 65.2.25.152
```

for all the servers

Comment: `awk` can give that output. Have you made any attempts?

Answer (score 5):

Using sed

```
sed '/^Host/{s/[^ ]* //;:1;N;s/\n.*HostName */\t/;t2;b1;:2;p};d' file

aws_server      65.2.25.152
```

---

Modified version that's more robust for multiple hosts,missing HostNames

```
sed ':1;s/\(.*\n\|^\)Host *//;N;s/\n.*HostName */\t/;t2;$!{b1;:2;p};d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

using awk

```
awk '{if($1=="Host")k=$2;if($1=="HostName")printf("%s\t%s\n",k,$2)}' file
```

Comment: Awk automatically does `if`'s before blocks so you could write as `awk '$1=="Host"{k=$2}$1=="HostName"{printf("%s\t%s\n",k,$2)}'`, good answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` for this:

```
awk '
    # Save the host when we see it.
    /^Host/ {
        host=$2
        next
    }
    # If we have a host and are on a HostName line
    host && $1 == "HostName" {
        # Print the Host and HostName values
        printf "%s"OFS"%s\n", host, $2
        host=""
        next
    }
    # If we have a HostName without a Host clear the host (should not happen but just to be safe)
    $1 == "HostName" {
        host=""
    }
' .ssh/config
```

Comment: Think you may have meant to use printf `print "%s\t%s"`, although in that case you may want to add a `\n` to the end so it doesn't mess up the prompt.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ I'm guessing you meant `printf` just like I did. =) And yes, the newline is important too. Thanks.